# Dictionaries appended and updating create clones

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

I need it to stop cloning and add the new dictionaries to the list

I even tried update for updating dictionaries but did not work

```
import random

# This line creates a set with 6 random numbers
#We use a 22 range or similar, otherwise the players will not get enough correct numbers for creating a solution in a learning enviroment.
lottery_numbers = set(random.sample(range(22), 6))

# Here are your players; they all decided to get their numbers randomly find out who has the most numbers matching lottery_numbers!
players = [
    {'name': 'Rolf', 'numbers': set(random.sample(range(22), 6))},
    {'name': 'Charlie', 'numbers':set(random.sample(range(22), 6))},
    {'name': 'Anna', 'numbers': set(random.sample(range(22), 6))},
    {'name': 'Jen', 'numbers': set(random.sample(range(22), 6))}
]

num_player = [1000]
dicc_A = {}


print("Lottery numbers ", lottery_numbers)
print("")
for a in players:
  print("Line by line",a)
  print("")
  for i,j in a.items():
    if i == "name":
      dicc_A["Name"] = j
      print("name Dicc: ", dicc_A)
    if i == "numbers":
      dicc_A["Num"] = j.intersection(lottery_numbers)


      print("  xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR ",num_player)
      
      print("******number Dicc: ", dicc_A)
      num_player.append(dicc_A)

      print("")
      print("  ///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR ",num_player)
```

This is the output****************

Lottery numbers  {5, 9, 13, 14, 19, 20}

Line by line {'name': 'Rolf', 'numbers': {2, 3, 5, 11, 12, 19}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Rolf'}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {19, 5}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {19, 5}}]

Line by line {'name': 'Charlie', 'numbers': {0, 4, 7, 8, 17, 20}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {19, 5}}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {20}}]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {20}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {20}}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {20}}]

Line by line {'name': 'Anna', 'numbers': {4, 5, 6, 10, 16, 17}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {20}}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {5}}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {5}}]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {5}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {5}}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {5}}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {5}}]

Line by line {'name': 'Jen', 'numbers': {2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {5}}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {9, 5}}]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I need it to stop cloning and add the new dictionaries to the list
I even tried update for updating dictionaries but did not work

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry. now I see to append a dictionary to a  list you need to create a copy
So the solution was simply this

```
import random

# This line creates a set with 6 random numbers
#We use a 22 range or similar, otherwise the players will not get enough correct numbers for creating a solution in a learning enviroment.
lottery_numbers = set(random.sample(range(22), 6))

# Here are your players; they all decided to get their numbers randomly find out who has the most numbers matching lottery_numbers!
players = [
    {'name': 'Rolf', 'numbers': set(random.sample(range(22), 6))},
    {'name': 'Charlie', 'numbers':set(random.sample(range(22), 6))},
    {'name': 'Anna', 'numbers': set(random.sample(range(22), 6))},
    {'name': 'Jen', 'numbers': set(random.sample(range(22), 6))}
]

num_player = [1000]
dicc_A = {}


print("Lottery numbers ", lottery_numbers)
print("")
for a in players:
  print("Line by line",a)
  print("")
  for i,j in a.items():
    if i == "name":
      dicc_A["Name"] = j
      print("name Dicc: ", dicc_A)
    if i == "numbers":
      dicc_A["Num"] = j.intersection(lottery_numbers)


      print("  xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR ",num_player)
      
      print("******number Dicc: ", dicc_A)


      dictionary_copy = dicc_A.copy()
      num_player.append(dictionary_copy)




      print("")
      print("  ///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR ",num_player)
    
    
    
    print("")
    print("")
```

*************outputs

Lottery numbers  {2, 7, 12, 17, 20, 21}

Line by line {'name': 'Rolf', 'numbers': {3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 14}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Rolf'}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}]

Line by line {'name': 'Charlie', 'numbers': {4, 8, 10, 12, 13, 18}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}]

Line by line {'name': 'Anna', 'numbers': {10, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {12}}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {17, 20, 21}}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {17, 20, 21}}]

Line by line {'name': 'Jen', 'numbers': {3, 6, 8, 9, 13, 14}}

name Dicc:  {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': {17, 20, 21}}

xxxxxxxxxx  NUMPLAYER before APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {17, 20, 21}}]
******number Dicc:  {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': set()}

///////// NUMPLAYER after APPEND inside FOR  [1000, {'Name': 'Rolf', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Num': {12}}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Num': {17, 20, 21}}, {'Name': 'Jen', 'Num': set()}]